# PDF (embedded Fonts) to EPS (path only)

Tags: windows, pdf, document-converter

I need a tool that converts a PDF with embedded fonts to an EPS.
The resulting EPS should contain only paths instead of font/text information.

It can be a freeware or a paid product.

It should be executable on a windows machine (GUI or Cmd based).

---

**Update:** I found also a way to do it in Acrobat: https://bestfontforward.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/outlining-text-in-adobe-acrobat-x/

Comment: Converting text to path usually results in incorrect kerning and lots of headaches ([here is an example from when I tried it using Inkscape](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDEbj.png)). Consider settling for an embedded image instead. I ended up using ImageMagick to convert the pdf into a high-density `png` image. You could do that with `eps` as well using `convert -density 600x600 text.pdf -quality 100 text.eps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org/en/) for this - either from the GUI or via the command line with:

```
inkscape input.pdf --export-eps=output.eps
```

When saving to eps from the GUI you are first prompted to specify where you wish to save then have a dialogue with an option to convert texts to paths:

[image: EPS Prompt]

Inkscape is available on Windows, Linux & OS-X, it is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in a *reliable* way, you can use a two step process:

1. Convert the text characters in the PDF to a series of small vector outlines. This can be done by **[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)** (version 9.15 or later) with the parameter `-dNoOutputFonts`:

   ```
   gswin64c.exe -o outlines.pdf   \
                -dNoOutputFonts   \
                -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
                 input.pdf
   ```
2. Convert the newly created PDF to EPS with the help of **[`pdftops`](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)** (which is part of the XPDF suite of tools):

   ```
   pdftops.exe -level 3       \
               -origpagesizes \
               -eps           \
                outlines.pdf  \
                outlines.eps
   ```

---

You can also try to do it with Ghostscript (version 9.15 or later) in single step, but it won't work as reliably:

```
    gswin64c.exe -o outlines.eps    \
                 -dNoOutputFonts    \
                 -dEPSFitPage       \       
                 -sDEVICE=eps2write \
                  input.pdf
```